# Erro em leitura/manipulação do nome do arquivo: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, arquivo-zip

Olá ! Estou tentando criar um código em que leia um arquivo zipado e extraia todas as pastas dentro dentro deste zip. O primeiro ponto é que esse arquivo zip que é baixado vem sempre com um nome aleatório de combinações de números e letras e não sabia como conseguir fazer isso, então encontrei um tutorial na internet que mostra como localiza alguns arquivos em alguns pastas pelo tipo do arquivo e tentei adaptar ao meu problema, e cheguei ao seguinte código:

removido por questão de seg.

Existe alguma outra forma de tentar fazer o que eu estou tentando fazer?

Answer (score 1):

A [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) afirma que o primeiro parâmetro de `ZipFile` deve ser:

1. Uma string com o *path* para um arquivo ZIP

   ```
    import zipfile
    zf = zipfile.Zipfile("path/para/arquivo.zip")
   ```
2. Um objeto [*file-like*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)

   ```
    import zipfile
    with open("path/para/arquivo.zip", rb) as f:
        zf = zipfile.Zipfile(f)
   ```
3. Um objeto [*Path-like*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object)

   ```
    import zipfile
    from pathlib import Path

    p = Path("path/para/arquivo.zip")
    zf = zipfile.Zipfile(p)
   ```

E no seu caso, não é nenhum deles, pois você está passando uma lista de *paths*. O módulo acaba tratando sua lista como se fosse um arquivo, e erroneamente tenta invocar o método `seek` que pertence a objetos *file-like*.

Para seu código funcionar, basta você executar o seu código para cada elemento da lista ao invés da lista inteira.

Seu exemplo modificado ficaria:

```
for path in encontraArquivosEmPastaRecursivamente('.zip', 'C:\\Users\\x\\Downloads'):
    zipado = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    zipado.extractall()
```

---

***PS**: Vale verificar a nota de segurança do método [`extractall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall), segue uma tradução livre:*

> **Aviso**:
> Nunca extraia arquivos de fontes não-confiáveis sem uma inspeção adequada.
> É possível que arquivos sejam criados fora da pasta, por exemplo, membros que tem nomes de arquivos absolutos começando com `/` ou nomes com `..`.
> Este módulo tenta prevenir isso.